# Why does cocoapods clone spec-repo every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I have a big project and I like to jump back and forth my git history..

sometimes when I go to the top of my git history.. and I run my Xcode project it fails with the following error:
[image: screen shot 2014-09-30 at 12 34 33 pm]

if I run `pod install`.. I get this:

```
pod install --verbose

Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
  $ /usr/bin/git ls-remote
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
  09b0e7431ab82063d467296904a85d72ed40cd73  HEAD
  ..
```

so it's basically doing a `pod setup`.. which is defined as

```
$ pod setup

  Creates a directory at `~/.cocoapods/repos` which will hold your spec-repos.
  This is where it will create a clone of the public `master` spec-repo from:

      https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

  If the clone already exists, it will ensure that it is up-to-date.
```

but I've used cocoapods many times before.. but If I go to my home directory I don't see this `~/.cocoapods/repos` directory.. so does this mean it will have to clone this pod spec repo everytime? this is a huge repo in [size](https://api.github.com/repos/CocoaPods/Specs) and it's very time consuming to update it every time.. how do I ensure that this doesn't happen again?  is there a way to skip downloading this gigantic repo to begin with?

Comment: hmm... not sure why but your setup seems broken. I move in my git history daily and never had an issue / never had to re-clone the podspecs repo. Maybe a permissions problem on `~/.cocoapods` ?

Comment: `~/.cocoapods` doesn't exist!

Comment: And does `pod setup` yield any errors?

Comment: No it just takes for ever like pod install

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `.gitignore` file is excluding your `Pods` folder. When you switch commeits, it detects that your `Pods` folder is out of sync with your `Podfile.lock` (which points to which specific versions of the pods should be on `Pods`).

I suggest to unignore that folder and commit it to your main repo. That way you will be able to checkout git commits freely without having to run any pod commands.